# How to extend Float and Array classes using modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module

When defining new methods for the Float and Array classes in a module, I am finding that the
methods are not acknowledged as methods, though the module is included. I am just becoming
familiar with the use of modules in Ruby, so I would appreciate any help. The code follows:

---

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

module NewMath

    include Math        

puts("Hello from NewMath")

class Array

    def mean
        raise Exception, "#{self} should be a uniform array of numbers" if     
           !hasElementsOfUniformType?( self) || !self.first.is_a?(Numeric)
        sum = inject(&:+)
        
        return (self.first.is_a?(Integer)) ? sum / size : sum / size.to_f
    end
    
    def standardDeviation
        raise Exception, "#{self} should be a uniform array of numbers" if  \
              !hasElementsOfUniformType?( self) || !self.first.is_a?(Numeric)
        raise ArgumentError, "#{self} should be an array of more than 1 numbers" if \
              self.size < 2     

        mn = self.mean          
        sumOfDeviationSqr = self.map { |x| x.to_f - mn.to_f } \
           .map { |deviation| deviation * deviation }.reduce(:+) / (size - 1).to_f
        
        return  Math.sqrt(sumOfDeviationSqr)    
    end
end

class Integer
    def notToExceed( limit)
        return (self > limit) ? limit : self
    end
end 

class Float
    def constrainAndFormat(low:, high:, decimalPlaces:)
    raise Exception, "low: #{low} should be a Float" if !low.is_a?(Float)
    raise Exception, "high: #{high} should be a Float value > #{lo}" \
         if !high.is_a?(Float) || high < low
    raise Exception, "decimalPlaces: #{decimalPlaces} should be a positive integer" \
         if (decimalPlaces < 1)
        item = (self > high) ? high : (self < low) ? low : self
        
        factor = 1.upto(decimalPlaces).map { |i| 10.to_f }.reduce(:*)                       
        truncate = (item * factor).to_i.to_f
        return truncate / factor            
    end
end
end

include NewMath


print("\n Array's public instance methods: #{Array.public_instance_methods}")
print
print("\n Array's included modules: #{Array.included_modules}")
print
list = []
100.times.each do 
    list << rand(1..100)
end
print("\n list = #{list}\n")
print("\n s.d. = #{list.standardDeviation}\n")

a = list.mean
print("\n mean = #{a}\n")

print("\n Float's public instance methods: #{Float.public_instance_methods}")
l = 1.0 /3.0
print("\n l = #{l} , #{l.constrainAndFormat(low: 0.0, high:2.0, decimalPlaces:4)}")


************************* end of code *******************************************

Mean, standardDeviation, and constrainAndFormat are undefined.  Array's list of public  
instance methods excludes standardDeviation.
```

Array's public instance methods: [:to_h, :include?, :at, :fetch, :last, :union, :difference, :push, :append, :pop, :shift, :unshift, :each_index, :join, :rotate, :rotate!, :sort!, :sort_by!, :collect!, :map!, :select!, :filter!, :keep_if, :values_at, :delete_at, :delete_if, :reject!, :transpose, :fill, :assoc, :rassoc, :uniq!, :compact, :compact!, :flatten, :flatten!, :shuffle!, :shuffle, :*, :+, :permutation, :&, :repeated_permutation, :combination, :sample, :repeated_combination, :product, :bsearch, :-, :sort, :bsearch_index, :count, :find_index, :select, :filter, :reject, :collect, :map, :first, :all?, :any?, :one?, :none?, :reverse_each, :zip, :take, :take_while, :drop, :drop_while, :cycle, :sum, :uniq, :|, :insert, :<=>, :<<, :index, :rindex, :replace, :==, :clear, :pack, :[], :[]=, :empty?, :eql?, :max, :min, :reverse, :inspect, :concat, :prepend, :reverse!, :length, :size, :each, :to_ary, :delete, :to_a, :to_s, :slice, :slice!, :dig, :hash, :find, :entries, :sort_by, :grep, :grep_v, :detect, :find_all, :flat_map, :collect_concat, :inject, :reduce, :partition, :group_by, :minmax, :min_by, :max_by, :minmax_by, :member?, :each_with_index, :each_entry, :each_slice, :each_cons, :each_with_object, :chunk, :slice_before, :slice_after, :slice_when, :chunk_while, :chain, :lazy, :instance_variable_defined?, :remove_instance_variable, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variables, :singleton_method, :method, :public_send, :define_singleton_method, :public_method, :extend, :to_enum, :enum_for, :===, :=~, :!~, :respond_to?, :freeze, :object_id, :send, :display, :nil?, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :itself, :yield_self, :then, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :frozen?, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :equal?, :!, :**id**, :instance_exec, :!=, :instance_eval, :**send**]
Array's included modules: [Enumerable, NewMath, Math, Kernel]
list = [90, 61, 39, 63, 17, 39, 26, 9, 91, 69, 67, 39, 33, 13, 63, 68, 100, 58, 25, 3, 37, 28, 56, 43, 100, 43, 3, 3, 25, 97, 56, 20, 86, 25, 21, 60, 8, 20, 87, 32, 1, 97, 52, 51, 83, 86, 57, 55, 91, 16, 49, 83, 46, 82, 58, 56, 40, 22, 8, 60, 91, 5, 50, 11, 57, 27, 53, 39, 83, 12, 90, 92, 61, 83, 31, 87, 63, 97, 76, 66, 58, 24, 8, 82, 17, 44, 76, 43, 71, 29, 95, 34, 22, 54, 90, 5, 11, 98, 26, 79]
Traceback (most recent call last):
./newTesting.rb:63:in `<main>': undefined method` standardDeviation' for #Array:0x00007fdd9514c768 (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 2):

You've defined three classes, `NewMath::Array`, `NewMath::Integer` and `NewMath::Float`.

Then, you've included the `NewMath` module into `main` (the top level scope). `include` does a handful of things, but "merging classes with the same name" isn't one of them. It will not "merge" `Array` with `NewMath::Array`.

What you're trying to do is probably:

```rb
module NewMath
  module Array
    def foo
      puts "foo"
    end
  end
end

Array.include(NewMath::Array)

[].foo # prints "foo"
```

Good on you for trying to do it this way b/c this retains the owner:

```rb
pry(main)> [].method(:foo).owner
=> NewMath::Array
```

Which makes code easy to find. This is in contrast to opening up the class directly:

```rb
# this could be in any file, anywhere
class Array
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

[].method(:bar).owner # => Array  (gives you no indication where it came from)
```